# My form isn't saved in database based on my report

Tags: php, html, database, laravel

I'm making a new report system, I'm at beginning, the design is already done, but when I press on submit, nothing is happening in database, I get 0 records.What's wrong in my code?Or maybe I need to add something more?

**My view:**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="top: 50px">
      <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: none">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <section>
        <div class="wizard col-md-6" style="right: 5px;margin: 0px auto">
            <div class="wizard-inner">
                <div class="connecting-line"></div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" style="margin: 0px auto">

                    <li role="presentation" class="active">
                        <a href="#step1" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step1" role="tab" title="Step 1">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step2" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step2" role="tab" title="Step 2">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="icon-note"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation" class="disabled">
                        <a href="#step3" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="step3" role="tab" title="Step 3">
                            <span class="round-tab">
                                <i class="icon-check"></i>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>

            <form role="form">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" role="tabpanel" id="step1">
                        <h3>Why are you reporting this content :</h3>

                        <ul style="list-style: none">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-9" name="why_reporting" value="Spam">
    <label for="box-9">Spam</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
    <small id="box-9-s" style="display: none">I consider this content irrelevant and annoying.</small>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-10" name="why_reporting" value="Fake Profile">
    <label for="box-10">Fake Profile</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-10-s" style="display: none">This content was posted by way of a profile that clearly doesn't represent a real person.
</small>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-11" name="why_reporting" value="Advertising">
    <label for="box-11">Advertising</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-11-s" style="display: none">This content is or contains advertising.
</small>
  </li>
   <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-12" name="why_reporting" value="Untrustworthy source">
    <label for="box-12">Untrustworthy source</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-12-s" style="display: none">This content is from an untrustworthy source and contains unverifiable statements.
</small>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-13" name="why_reporting" value="Defamatory">
    <label for="box-13">Defamatory</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-13-s" style="display: none">The reported content is insulting or defamatory to me or other people.
</small>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-14" name="why_reporting" value="Violence or pornography">
    <label for="box-14">Violence or pornography</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-14-s" style="display: none">This content contains violence or pornography.
</small>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-15" name="why_reporting" value="Violates IP rights">
    <label for="box-15">Violates IP rights</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-15-s" style="display: none">This content includes third-party content (e.g. an image) posted under their own name.
</small>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="box-16" name="why_reporting" value="Promotes structural distribution measures">
    <label for="box-16">Promotes structural distribution measures</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
    <small id="box-16-s" style="display: none">This content promotes a chain distribution system, multilevel selling or pyramid sales.
</small>
  </li>
  <li >
    <input type="radio" id="box-17" name="selector">
    <label for="box-17" id="other">Other</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
     <div class="form-group" id="mydiv" style="display: none">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Please let us know why you're reporting this content:
" style="resize: none" name="why_reporting_message"></textarea>
  </div>
  </li>
</ul>


                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="button" class="btn btn-primary next-step">Save and continue</button></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step2">
                        <h3>Why would you like to report this?</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="5" style="resize: none" placeholder="
Please let us know why you're reporting this content:" name="additional_message"></textarea>
  </div>
                        <ul class="list-inline pull-right">
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default prev-step">Previous</button></li>
                            <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-default next-step">Skip</button></li>
                            <li><button style="background-color: #18ba9b;border-color: white" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-info-full next-step">Submit your report</button></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel" id="step3">
                        <h2 class="title-box-v2" style="font-size: 17px !important;line-height: 35px">We'll look into this as soon as possible. Thanks for helping us improve the quality of content on Workstickers.</h2>
                        <p style="text-align: center">You have successfully completed all steps.Flagged content and users are reviewed by Workstickers staff 24 hours a day, seven days a week to determine whether they violate Community Guidelines. Accounts are penalized for Community Guidelines violations, and serious or repeated violations can lead to account termination.
</p>
<div style="text-align: center;margin-top: 50px">If you've changed your mind -  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: underline;color: #18ba9b;font-weight: 700">Cancel report</a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
   </div>
</div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



                                <!-- END MY MODAL -->
```

**Model Reports**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reports extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reports';

    // public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'news_id','opinion_id','event_id','career_solutions_id','why_reporting','why_reporting_message','additional_message','private'
    ];


    public function career_solutionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareerSolution','career_solution_id','id');
    }
     public function eventReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Event','event_id','id');
    }
     public function newsReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\News','news_id','id');
    }
     public function opinionReport()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Opinion','opinion_id','id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

}
```

**My controller:**

```
 public function careerReport(requ $request)
    {

        $report = \App\Reports::create([
                        'user_id' => $request['user_id'],
                        'career_solution_id' =>$request['career_solution_id'],
                        'why_reporting' =>$request['why_reporting'],
                        'why_reporting_message' =>$request['why_reporting_message'],
                        'additional_message' =>$request['additional_message'],

                    ]);

        if($report != ""){
            flash('Career solution report submited', 'success');
        }else{
            flash('Career solution report', 'warning');
        }

        return Redirect::back();


    }
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('career_review', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReview');
Route::post('career_report', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReport');
```

I have tried to reproduce my review comments system, but I don't know why isn't working. At submit, my page is refreshing and nothing happens but in my link I have this ( for example ) : `https://my-link.com/why_reporting=Spam&why_reporting_message=&additional_message=testarea+mea`

Comment: Nothing in your log? `public function careerReport(requ $request)` What is `requ`?

Comment: @kerbholz `requ` is `use Illuminate\Http\Request as requ;` , I didn't make this code, I'm just trying to add something new here, based on the old content.

Comment: Do you get any errors, or simply page refreshes, and nothing happens?

Comment: @zlatan, only page refreshes, nothing happens but in my link I have this : `why_reporting=Spam&why_reporting_message=&additional_message=testarea+mea`

Comment: Missing `@csrf` in your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your form submit destination and submit type inside Form tag. Currently there is nothing inside form tag. And don't forget to add csrf field in form.

Example:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ action('CareerSolutionController@careerReport') }}" method="post">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

or

```
<form role="form" action="{{ url('career_report') }}" method="post">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer.I added this and now, when I click on submit button, I'm redirectet to 404 page, but my link is something like `/career_report?_token=RT1DZZg2DmUrCxoi628og4sm7STKo4nV4AOGnONR&why_reporting=Untrustworthy+source&why_reporting_message=&additional_message=ewfwefew`

Comment: @AndreiNagy add csrf token in form. just after form tag use this `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: Yes, it's already here :( `<form role="form" action="{{ action('CareerSolutionController@careerReport') }}" type="post">
   {!! csrf_field() !!}`

Comment: there was a mistake, i've edited my answer. replace type with method

Comment: Yes, now I have only a little step :) `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null` .`user_id` should be the user_id of auth user when the form is sent.

Comment: make `user_id` nullable in database or add some value in `user_id` while saving data.

Comment: Yes, it's saved.But do you know how to save user id of auth user in `user_id`?

Comment: It should `Auth::user()->id()` or `Auth::id()`

Comment: `'user_id' => Auth::user()->id()`, like this?

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, you never defined form action in your blade, so the form doesnt know what to do. Change your form opening to this:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ action('CareerSolutionController@careerReport') }}>
```

And don't forget to add crsf token right below it:

```
@csrf
```

Or for convinience, add custom name to your route:

```
Route::post('career_report', 'CareerSolutionController@careerReport')->as('career.report');
```

And use it in your form like this:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('career.report') }}" method=POST>
```

Comment: I made like this, but same problem as the next answer, at submit I'm redirected to 404 page.

Comment: That route is `POST`, but the form method isn't

Comment: as @kerbholz said, change the form method to POST, see my updated answer

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null`, now I have this problem :( `user_id` should be the user_id of auth user when the form is sent.

Comment: Can you `dd($request)`on top of your controller, and paste the output. I think you might be retreiving data incorrectly. Use `$request->` insted of `$request[]`

Comment: You don't have `user_id` in your request, and you're trying to save it. I don't see it defined anywhere in your form. If you want to save users id, make a hidden input with name `user_id` and value `Auth::user()->id`

Comment: @zlatan this ` <input name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">` or ` <input name="user_id" value=" Auth::user()->id ">` isn't working :(